# Union with Negation, Java RegExp

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation

I would like to use union between the two regular expressions: 
`"abc"` and `^(?!.*Blah).*$`

But when I try:

```
abc^(?!.*Blah).*$ or [abc]^(?!.*Blah).*$
```

it doesn't work, does anyone have a solution?

In plain English, the ideal regular expression I want is `"abc"` followed by anything except `"Blah"`.

Comment: Remove the `^` from the first regex.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:-

```
abc(?!.*Blah).*$
```

ie, remove the `^`

instead of

```
 abc^(?!.*Blah).*$
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [Java Regex Boundary Matchers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/bounds.html) you will see that the `^` character in this context is trying to match the beginning of a line, which is not what you want.

As suggested you may want to use `abc(?!.*Blah).*$` or if you still require line boundary matching then `^abc(?!.*Blah).*$`